# Finding the number of pixels in a numpy array equal to a given color

Tags: python, numpy

I have been scouring around and can't seem to find an answer to this question. Say I have a given RGB value, i.e. (255,0,25) or something like that.

I have a ndarray called 'img' of shape (height, width, 3). Now, I want to find the number of pixels in this array that equal my color. I thought doing

`(img==(255,0,25)).sum()` would work, but even if my image is a comprised only of the color (255,0,25), I will overcount and it seems that this is summing up when r=255, 0, or 25, and when g=255,0, or 25, and when b=255,0, or 25.

I have been searching the numpy documentation, but I can't find a way to compare pixel-wise, and not element-wise. Any ideas?

Comment: `(img == (255,0,25)).all(axis=1).sum()`

Comment: @furas Do you mean `axis=-1`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I tested on 1D list of pixels but for 2D array of pixels it has to be `axis=2` and it gives the same as `axis=-1`

Comment: Exactly my point. In general, it'd better be `axis=-1`. That said, an image is more likely a 3-D array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it compares every value in `RGB` separatelly so every pixel gives tuple `(True, True, True)` and you have to convert `(True, True, True)` to `True` using `.all(axis=...)`

For 3D array `(y,x,RGB)` you have to use `.all(axis=2)` or more universal `.all(axis=-1)` as noticed @QuangHoang in comment.

```
print( (img == (255,0,25)).all(axis=-1).sum() )
```

---

```
import numpy as np

img = np.array([[(255,0,25) for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)])
#print(img)

print( (img == (255,0,25)).all(axis=-1).sum() )  # 9

img[1][1] = (0,0,0)
img[1][2] = (0,0,0)
#print(img)

print( (img == (255,0,25)).all(axis=-1).sum() )  # 7
```